# How do I create and use a Stack of a type known at runtime

Tags: c#

I have a method that creates a `Stack` for a type specified at runtime like this

```
public object CreateStackForType(Type childType)
{
   return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Stack<>).MakeGenericType(childType));
}
```

This appears to work to create the `Stack` object, but now I don't know how to cast the returned object to a `Stack` of the correct type so that I can push elements onto it.

For example

```
public object FillStack(Type childType, object[] values)
{
   object myStack = CreateStackForType(childType);

   foreach (object value in values)
   {
      // I want to push 'value' onto 'myStack', but I don't know how to cast 'myStack'
      // I want something like ((Stack<childType>)myStack).Push(value)
   } 

   return myStack;
}
```

I tried doing `((Stack<object>)myStack).Push(value)`, but that gives tells me "specified cast is not valid".

Comment: what about the objects in the `values` array? make sure you are not doing something like converting `hello` to `int `

Comment: How are you calling `FilleStack` in the first place? Why aren't you using generics _throughout_?

Comment: Why not use a non-generic `Stack`?

Comment: @Dai I'm loading a text file and using reflection to create and populate objects based on the values in the text file.  I'm not using generics throughout because I don't know the types at compile time.

Comment: @Llama I'm not using a generic `Stack` because elsewhere in the code, I'm assigning the returned `Stack` object to a `Stack` with the type parameter defined, such as `Stack<MyClass>`

Comment: @BenRubin You shouldn't really use generics if you don't know the type at compile-time. Is it a small set of types defined in your textfile or is it unbounded and arbitrary?

Comment: @Dai It's unbounded.

Comment: @BenRubin That's a really bad _code smell_ because it means an attacker can make your program instantiate any built-in type then.... the same underlying vulnerability as this epic fail: https://www.darkreading.com/application-security/why-the-java-deserialization-bug-is-a-big-deal

Comment: @Dai Well it's not totally unbounded.  The way that the deserialization runs, it'll only deserialize types that are used within my program, so the system wouldn't open itself up to that kind of mischief.  I meant it's unbounded as in there are a lot of potential types, and the list will get larger the more code I write.

Comment: @BenRubin If the text file gets to specify the type-name - and your program doesn't validate it - then your program _will_ be vulnerable. It's a problem _inherent_ in arbitrary deserialization. Anyway, from what you've posted I think you really need to completely re-think how your program is implemented because from my perspective you're using the wrong tools for the job - or at the very least **post the code** that reads a file and calls `FillStack`.

Comment: @Dai The program validates the type to the extent that the type has to be something that's already being actively used.  I don't know of any way to implement it differently.  I'm trying to serialize a scene in Unity and types in Unity don't support serialization, so I'm having to roll my own.  The actual code is pretty big, so I can't really post it.

Comment: @Dai To go off on a tangent, do you know how developers updated their code to prevent that attack you referenced, since they will have to deserialize the untrusted data?

Comment: @BenRubin The quick-fix solution is to have a whitelist of permitted type-names. A better solution is to define your own _serialization schema_ that serializes only data, and never any specific type-names. You could use JSON, for example, which does not include type-names, and is up to the consumer to decide what actual types to use. Overall, this is a large topic that can't be adequately discussed in a single SO question. My overall conclusion is that you need to start-over and devise a way that doesn't involve needing to serialize specific type-names. Why not just use `JsonConvert`?

Comment: @Dai Thank you for the answer about that vulnerability.  The reason I'm not using any built-in serialization is because of what's necessary to serialize a scene in Unity.  Unity's `MonoBehaviour`s don't support serialization.  And there are also other things about the serialization that I'm doing in a non-standard way in order to do the sort of serialization/deserialization that's needed to save/load Unity scenes.  I'm not trying to be difficult; I'd love it if there were an easier way.  I've tried a bunch of things, and I can't figure out a better way to do this with Unity scenes.

Comment: @BenRubin Right, and that means there's a _lot of details_ that are missing from your question-post - that's why I can't really help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of the `dynamic` keyword and `Convert.ChangeType` method

```
FillStack(typeof(int), new object[] {1, 2, 3});

/****/

public static object FillStack(Type childType, object[] values)
{
    // myStack is a Stack<int> in that instance
    dynamic myStack = CreateStackForType(childType);

    foreach (object value in values)
    {
        // val is an int in that instance
        dynamic val = Convert.ChangeType(value, childType);
        myStack.Push(val);
    } 

    return myStack;
}
```

Comment: `dynamic` is not type-safe though.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for teaching me something.  I didn't know you could call methods with `dynamic` .  I guess I've got some reading to do.

Answer (score 2):

```
public object CreateStackForType(Type childType, out Delegate obj)
{
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Stack<>).MakeGenericType(childType));
    obj = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(childType), instance, "Push");
    return instance;
}

public object FillStack(Type childType, object[] values)
{
    object myStack = CreateStackForType(childType, out Delegate push);
    foreach (object value in values)
        push.DynamicInvoke(value);
    return myStack;
}
```

But this is inefficient when add a large amount of data.

If you just want to initialize a stack with an array, this is more effective.

```
public object FillStack(Type childType, Array values)
{
    return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Stack<>).MakeGenericType(childType), values);
}
```

Comment: I'd change `FillStack`'s return-type from `Object` to `ICollection`, as both `System.Collections.Stack` and `System.Collections.Generic.Stack<>` implement `ICollection`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I didn't know that you could use `CreateInstance` to initialize collections.